# How to code the logic behind the bridge in the TumbleSeed ? Unity

Tags: rotation, logic, 2d, unity-game-engine, seesaw

I have tried to code the bridge like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nstFXogJ-D4) .I have used RotateAround and set 2 points which is left and right point of the seesaw/bridge but when i rotate left and rotate right the x axis of the bridge ran off little by little eventually gone from the screen. Can anyone provide me the logic behind this ?

Comment: If it is like the video, you should rotate around Z axis

Comment: i try rotate z-axis but it seems like the whole bridge/seesaw are turning, but in the video the bridge only up on right/left side , the position of the left/right side seems unchanged.

Comment: What i've understand from the video, When left side goes up, right side goes down. Doesn't it how it suppose to be ?

Comment: My case will happend if you rotate the bridge from the middle. You can rotate it from the left side, left side will stay put, and right side will go up and down

Comment: When left side goes up , right will stay with its position. What you mean is that I RotateAround the side of the left or right?

Comment: To left go up/down, Right should rotateAround it self in order to right stay put in position.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem , when we rotatearound left point/right point the position x of the left/right point is moved so to solve that issues when rotating always set the position.x to 0 so that it will achieve the bridge in the TumbleSeed.